# Como colocar borda na seta do select com CSS?

Tags: html, css, html5, css3

Tenho esse select com html e css:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Como faço para colocar uma borda do lado da seta?

Assim:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Já tentou usar assim.  Ex: select {
   
}

Comment: Aqui tem um exemplo que pode te ajudar: https://codepen.io/vkjgr/pen/VYMeXp

Comment: @EmersonVieira Ajudou muito. Obrigado!!

Answer (score 2):

Com o exemplo do @Emerson Vieira, fiz algumas alterações para obter o resultado que espera:

```css
select {
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0%, transparent 0%),
    linear-gradient(0deg, transparent 0%, transparent 0%),
    linear-gradient(to right, #ccc, #ccc);
  
  background-position:
    calc(100%) calc(1em + 1px),
    calc(100%) calc(1em + 1px),
    calc(100% - 1.5em) 0.2em;
  background-size:5px 5px, 5px 5px, 1px 2.5em;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  width: 200px;
  padding: 10px;
}
```

```html
<select class="select">
  <option>Arroz</option>
  <option>Feijão</option>
  <option>macarrão</option>
</select>
```